# I want to print another document using a button in HTML

Tags: html

I have two HTML Documents and from a button on the first document, I want to print the second document.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.print();
}
</script>
```

This is what I have previously used but this just prints the same document when I need it to print another document. How do I change my function to print another HTML document?

Comment: For the code above, you can just replace myFunction() with print() and remove the <script> part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an iframe (a server is needed!):

```
<iframe id="frameId" src="another_doc.html" style="display:none" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-modals" ></iframe>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('frameId').contentWindow.print()">Print another page</button>
```

Here is a [little demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e1cgL8kn/).

Comment: Yup! This worked a charm! Thank you so much, I didn't even consider using an iframe for anything but videos.